# Multiple Vuetify Data Table adjust there size according to the largest table in the page and table structure change?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify Data Table, I have 3 data tables on the page and all the tables change their size according to the largest table on that page but I don't want this feature. I want that they should capture the size which they required to and not extend the table size according to the largest one.
Does someone have any idea why this behavior is there?
Here is the structure of my code:

```html
<tamplate>
  <div align="center" style="width: 100%">
    <v-container grid-list-md fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card>
            <v-data-table> </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
    <v-container grid-list-md fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card>
            <v-data-table> </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
    <v-container grid-list-md fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card>
            <v-data-table> </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</tamplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table takes all the possible width for it, which is specified by the grid. Try changing the grid parameters:

```
// First table
<v-flex xs12>
...
// Second table
<v-flex xs10>
...
// Third table
<v-flex xs8>
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/y6cw1y0u/ ]